# Check format and get numbers with sscanf c++

Tags: c++, scanf

I need to check an array of chars for a specific simple format and get the values of two numbers inside it at the same time. The message format is: **START number number END**. All I could come up with was this:

```
int x,y;
if ( sscanf(buffer, "START %d %d END", &x, &y) != 2) 
    return false;
...
...
...
return true;
```

But this of course succeeds even after the ending being totally different because the numbers were obtained. What is the best way to do it? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: It looks like you've mixed up the contents of buffer and your string "START %d %d END". sscanf expects a buffer containing your string and a second string with your format data i.e.`sscanf("START 9 10 END", "%s %d %d %s",buff1, &x, &y,buff2)`. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Call sscanf with formatting string "START %d %d" and if everything is OK then call sscanf with formatting string "%s" and compare the result with "END".

Comment: @auburg, the format data **is** `"START %d %d END"`, i.e. the string must contain those ordinary characters. Using %s in a scanf format is dangerous and should always be avoided, your suggestion would be OK if you used %5s and %3s.

Comment: @user121270, see the comment above, %s is dangerous, your suggestion would be OK if you used %3s and passed a pointer to an array of at least 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the C standard I'm amazed that there is no portable way to detect this.

On Linux `errno` gets set and you can also use `ferror`. On Windows `errno` also gets set, but MSDN doesn't mention `ferror`.

---

You could do this instead for a messy but portable solution:

```
int x,y;
char d;
if ( sscanf(buffer, "START %d %d EN%c", &x, &y, &d) != 3 || 'D' != d)
    return false;
```

Comment: `ferror` is irrelevant for `sscanf` because it doesn't read from a file stream.

Comment: @JonathanWakely sorry I was reading the documentation for `fscanf` not `sscanf`.

Comment: Your solution fails for `buffer` holding **START <number> <number> END<some garbage>**

Comment: I have assured that there is nothing after END, thus this solution works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int x, y;
size_t pos = -1;
char str[4];
if (sscanf(buffer, "START %d %d %3s%zn", &x, &y, str, &pos) != 3 || strcmp(pos, "END") || pos != strlen(buffer)) 
    return false;
//...
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always found the use of sscanf() and similar functions troublesome.  Although the other solutions are much more elegant I prefer a simpler and more easy to maintain code based on strtok().  Here's a little program to experiment with:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char buf[250];

    const char* delimiters=" \n";

    while(fgets(buf,250,stdin)!=nullptr){
        // fgets() reads the newline...
        printf("%s",buf);
        // Tokenize the buffer using 'delimiters'.  The nullptr will re-use the same buffer.
        char* pBegin = strtok(buf,delimiters);
        char* pNumb1 = strtok(nullptr,delimiters);
        char* pNumb2 = strtok(nullptr,delimiters);
        char* pEnd   = strtok(nullptr,delimiters);
        // Protect our strcmp from a nullptr(missing data) and do some validity tests.
        if((pEnd!=nullptr)&&(strcmp(pBegin,"BEGIN")==0)&&(strcmp(pEnd,"END")==0)){
            printf("  Begin = '%s'\n",pBegin); 
            printf("  Numb1 = '%s'\n",pNumb1); 
            printf("  Numb2 = '%s'\n",pNumb2); 
            printf("  End   = '%s'\n",pEnd); 
        }else{
            printf("  Error!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And some test data (with some blank lines at the end):

```
BEGIN 106 635 END
BEGIN 107 636 END
BEGaN 108 637 ENDING
BeGIN 115 644 End
BEGIN 116 645 END
BEGIN 117 646 END of it all
BEgIN 128 657 END
BEGIN 129 658 END
BEGIN 130 659 Finish
131 660 END
BEGIN 662 END
BEGIN 136 665 
BEGIN 136 
BEGIN
```

And this would be the output ...

```
BEGIN 106 635 END
  Begin = 'BEGIN'
  Numb1 = '106'
  Numb2 = '635'
  End   = 'END'
BEGIN 107 636 END
  Begin = 'BEGIN'
  Numb1 = '107'
  Numb2 = '636'
  End   = 'END'
BEGaN 108 637 ENDING
  Error!
BeGIN 115 644 End
  Error!
BEGIN 116 645 END
  Begin = 'BEGIN'
  Numb1 = '116'
  Numb2 = '645'
  End   = 'END'
BEGIN 117 646 END of it all
  Begin = 'BEGIN'
  Numb1 = '117'
  Numb2 = '646'
  End   = 'END'
BEgIN 128 657 END
  Error!
BEGIN 129 658 END
  Begin = 'BEGIN'
  Numb1 = '129'
  Numb2 = '658'
  End   = 'END'
BEGIN 130 659 Finish
  Error!
131 660 END
  Error!
BEGIN 662 END
  Error!
BEGIN 136 665 
  Error!
BEGIN 136 
  Error!
BEGIN 
  Error!

  Error!
```